# Require a gem in all migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this gem in my gemfile (`gem "lhm", "~> 2.2.0", require: false`) that I want required in all migrations. Behavior similar to that of requiring `spec_helper` in all spec files.

I considered doing something with `bin/rails` or `bin/rake` but I don't want it required in all tasks, just migrations. Ie. `rake db:migrate` or the now alias `rails db:migrate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably don't have all the migrations using `lhm` I would suggest adding `require "lhm"` only to the migrations you're using. But to answer your question you could use rake's `enhance` method:

add the below to `lib/tasks/something.rake`:

```
namespace :load do
  namespace :lhm do
    desc "This just loads lhm"
    task lhm: :environment do
      require "lhm"
    end
  end
end

Rake::Task['db:migrate'].enhance(['load:lhm'])
```

As an example see [here](https://github.com/jchowit/multitenant/tree/9ec10fbb19f77cf59c77cb800e19ceca061e584f/lib/tasks)